# How to make js-code a little neater?

Tags: javascript

I have a working js program

```
function tic() {

    h = new Date().getHours().toString();
    m = new Date().getMinutes().toString();
    s = new Date().getSeconds().toString();

    t = `${h} ${m} ${s}`;

    document.getElementById("magic").innerHTML = t;
    console.log(t)           
}

setInterval(tic, 1000);
```

so I want to make it better, something like this

```
  function clock(i) {
    new Date.i.toString();
  }
    h = getHours
    m = getMinutes 
    s = getSeconds
    console.log(`${i.h} ${i.m} ${i.s}`)
```

but it should work either

---

```
   setInterval(() => { 
        t = new Date; 
        t.h = t.getHours; 
        t.m = t.getMinutes; 
        t.s = t.getSeconds; 
        console.log(t.h(), t.m(), t.s());},
        1000);
```

this it what I wanted ;)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Use a code linter

Comment: For code review, consider the [Code Review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: You don't call clock, and you should be using bracket notation, not dot notation in multiple places

Comment: Question is how to make work second part of code in js

Comment: epascarello — can you explain this more please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `i` is a datestring you could do it like:

```
 function clock(i) {
    i = new Date(i);
    var t = `${i.getHours()} ${i.getMinutes()} ${i.getSeconds()}`;
 }
```

Though I would suggest using better variable names. You don't need to call `toString()` because the js interpreter will coerce anything in the string literal `${}` to a string for you.

If you just want to get the current date / time

```
 function clock() {
    i = new Date();
    return `${i.getHours()} ${i.getMinutes()} ${i.getSeconds()}`;
 }

 var t = clock();
```

And you can do the same `document.getElementById("magic").innerHTML = t;` to display that data. If you add jQuery to your project you could make it even cleaner and say `$('#magic').html(t)`

Comment: Thank you, Robbie much!

Clean and simple, finally. 

jQuery nah, I need to learn js first =)

Comment: sure thing, don't hold yourself back too much jQuery is very helpful and vanilla js is not used much in production environments. Let me know if you've any questions

Comment: Oh, I suggested jQ is like a noob way, but ok, I will try, heh, thanks again!

Comment: and one more thing =)

why
console.log(clock() or clock.t);
is undefined ?

Comment: I edited my post, check it out. You need to return that value instead of referencing it as a property (although you could reference as a property if you defined that property inside the function)

Comment: return is a key)) I get it!